# Limits with bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm stuck on the following question which I believe I am overthinking,

Suppose that $\{x_n \}, \{y_n \}$ are bounded sequences, prove that $\exists \ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $1 \leq n_1 < n_2 <...$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k}=x$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty} y_{n_k}=y$.

My idea of the proof is as follows,

We know that both $\{x_n \}, \{y_n \}$ are bounded sequences and if we let $\{ x_{n_k} \}, \{ y_{n_k} \}$ be subsequences of $\{x_n \}, \{y_n \}$ then $\{ x_{n_k} \} \to x$ and $\{ y_{n_k} \} \to y$.

And from here I am stuck because I am not sure if I should use the definition of a limit for sequences or if I should go ahead and try to show that the two sequences are bounded and compact which would imply the result of $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k}=x$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty} y_{n_k}=y$.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Does a monotonic sub-sequence exist for either sequence? Might be a good place to start.

Comment: Not all subsequences of $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}$ converges. By Bolzano-Weierstrass a convergent subsequence exists for both, but you need to prove the result for the same choices of $n_k$.

Comment: Well since we have the condition that $1 \leq n_1 < n_2 <...$ wouldn't that mean that both sub-sequences are monotone?

Comment: Not true. $1 \le n_1 < n_2 < \dots$ means that $n_i$ are increasing indices, which says nothing about the subsequences themselves.

Comment: Ahh alright thank you, In that case, I guess I really am a bit lost of how/where t proceed next,

Comment: Okay so I believe I have a general idea now, I did the following more or less,
I let $\{x_n \} , \{ y_n \}$ have $\{x_{n_k} \} , \{ y_{n_k} \}$ be subsequences. I assumed that $\lim x_n=x$ and $\lim y_n=y$ and for any $\epsilon >0$ I have that $n \geq N \in \N$ such that $|x_n-x|< \epsilon $ and $|y_n-y|< \epsilon $. Now for any $k \geq K \in \N$ I have that $n_k \geq n_K \geq N$ which implies that $|x_n-x|< \epsilon =|x_{n_k}-x|< \epsilon$ and $|y_n-y|< \epsilon =|y_{n_k}-y|< \epsilon$ which will give me the required result.